# Remove duplicate in joining table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 4 table like these:
PROJECTS

```
ID - TITLE - PMJOIN_ID - RESPJOIN_ID
1 - TEST - 1 - 2
```

PMJOIN

```
ID - PROJECTS_ID - USER_ID
1 -1 - 1 
1 -1 - 2
```

RESPJOIN

```
ID - PROJECTS_ID - USER_ID
2 -1 - 2
```

USERS

```
ID - ALIAS 
1 - PIPPO
2 - PLUTO
```

I Want a query that list all projects with all pms and responsibles in one line. Concatenating the pms and responsibles with (,).

So the desired output would be:

```
1-TEST-PIPPO,PLUTO-PLUTO
```

All the join I tried provide duplicate rows.

Comment: What's the difference between `PMJOIN` and `RESPJOIN` tables ?

Comment: What have you already tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: The full query could help. I think you are searching for GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: PMJOIN and RESPJOIN are technical the same but refer to a different meaning. I can't find a way to differentiate in the join

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation functions like [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/), with appropriate Joins.

Check the following query:

```
SELECT p.ID, 
       p.TITLE, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u1.ALIAS) AS PMs, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u2.ALIAS) AS RESPs
FROM PROJECTS AS p 
JOIN PMJOIN AS pmj ON pmj.PROJECTS_ID = p.ID 
JOIN USERS AS u1 ON u1.ID = pmj.USER_ID 
JOIN RESPJOIN AS rj ON rj.PROJECTS_ID = p.ID 
JOIN USERS AS u2 ON u2.ID = rj.USER_ID 
GROUP BY p.ID, p.TITLE
```